Get-PnPSiteTemplate gets stuck for a long time on certain handlers
I'll preface this by saying I'm very new to SharePoint and to PowerShell, so please bear with me and I'm happy to edit the question or provide more information as needed!
Not sure if this context matters, but our organization wants to have a new SharePoint site (and linked Team) for each new client engagement, so my overall goal is to automate as much as possible the process of duplicating the site configuration each time. The most important components to be duplicated are a set of libraries and lists with several specific columns and views, and a Home page with a few Quick Links web parts (one with external links, the others with links to the abovementioned libraries and lists). There are some other things that would be handy to not have to adjust manually each time (navigation, a couple Power Automate flows) but for now we just need to launch and those are lower priority. Most of my library and list setup seems to be handled effectively by a site script, but since the Home page configuration can't be applied using site scripts I now have to figure out PnP PowerShell :)
I'm running the following in PowerShell to extract my PnP template:
$siteUrl = "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/MyClientTemplate"

# Connect to your SharePoint Online tenant
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Interactive
Set-PnPTraceLog -On -LogFile traceoutput.txt
Get-PnPSiteTemplate -Out template.xml

It seems to run fine, and makes it to the status message "Extracting Template from https://mytenant.sharepoint. [various handlers]" where it then cycles through what I guess are handlers for various components of the SharePoint site configuration. The problem is that certain handlers cause the script to hang for... a long time. Long enough for me to give up, but there's no error. If I use the -ExcludeHandlers parameter to exclude those that are slow/hanging, it'll move on, so thus far I'm excluding ApplicationLifecycleManagement and ImageRenditions because AFAIK I haven't done any customization of those things on my site. But now it's hanging on Navigation, and man, I really would rather include that in the template if possible!
If I ctrl+C out, the file template.xml has been created and does contain what appears to be a very large and complex PnP template, but I really don't know enough about what I'm looking at to see if it holds any clues to the issue. traceoutput.txt only contains one line that doesn't seem to tell me much.
Any troubleshooting ideas are welcomed--thanks!
Edited to add one other potential clue I just noticed: In the terminal, when the script is first running (after I confirm overwrite of the output file) it looks like this:
PS C:\Users\Rachel\OneDrive\Documents\PowerShell\Scripts> . 'C:\Users\Rachel\OneDrive\Documents\PowerShell\Scripts\SPOSiteScripts\createPnPTemplate.ps1'

Confirm
File C:\Users\Rachel\OneDrive\Documents\PowerShell\Scripts\template.xml exists, overwrite?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): Y
Extracting Template from https://mytenant.sharepoint. [some handler              ]

but when the status changes to a handler it's going to hang on, an extra prompt line appears above the status message:
PS C:\Users\Rachel\OneDrive\Documents\PowerShell\Scripts> . 'C:\Users\Rachel\OneDrive\Documents\PowerShell\Scripts\SPOSiteScripts\createPnPTemplate.ps1'

Confirm
File C:\Users\Rachel\OneDrive\Documents\PowerShell\Scripts\template.xml exists, overwrite?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): Y
PS C:\Users\Rachel\OneDrive\Documents\PowerShell\Scripts>
Extracting Template from https://mytenant.sharepoint. [Web Settings            ]


I realized I forgot to include one more bit of information and that ended up being the key to answering my own question. I was running the script directly in VSCode via the PowerShell extension. When I ran it in the regular PS terminal it worked fine. I have no idea what the underlying issue is, but this works for me and hopefully can help someone else in the future!
